# ¿Cómo cuento el número de elementos por cada categoría de una columna en un dataframe de R?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo una variable en un dataframe que es "tamaño".
'''

```
tamaño  Marca
------  -----
2       aaaa
2       tttt
6       gggg
4       vvvv
4       kkkk
2       llll
8       pppp
8       oooo
6       rrrr
```

'''
Entonces, me gustaría saber como puedo crear una función en R que me devuelva el conteo de las veces que aparece cada número en la columna "tamaño".

Ejemplo
'''

```
2 = 3 veces
4 = 2 veces
6 = 2 veces
8 = 2 veces
```

'''
Tengo esta función pero no me cuenta los valores de tamaño
'''

```
contar_tamaño <- function(x){
cont<-0
for (i in tamaño) {
if  (i == 2) { cont=cont + 1 } 
}
cont
}
contar_tamaño(df_variables$tamaño)
```

'''
**Es necesario que se cree una función como la del ejemplor*
Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No olvidemos la noble función `table()` que justamente crea una tabla de frecuencias:

```
table(df$tamaño)

2 4 6 8 
3 2 2 2
```

Y siempre en R base, tenemos `aggregate()`:

```
aggregate(Marca ~ tamaño, df, length)

  tamaño Marca
1      2     3
2      4     2
3      6     2
4      8     2
```

Answer (score 5):

Puedes hacerlo con el paquete `dplyr` usando la función `group_by()`.

```
df %>% group_by(tamaño) %>% count() %>% mutate(n=paste0(n, " Veces"))

  tamaño n      
   <dbl> <chr>  
1      2 3 Veces
2      4 2 Veces
3      6 2 Veces
4      8 2 Veces
```

Con R base solo tendrías que hacerlo con la función `table()`.

```
as.data.frame(table(df$tamaño))

  Var1 Freq
1    2    3
2    4    2
3    6    2
4    8    2
```